# vaultedShopperId Card Transactions

Tags: transactions, bluesnap

How do I get the list of all those Auth Capture type transactions for a specific vaultedShopperId?

Is there any way I can specify the vaultedShopperId in the Card Transactions Retrieve API?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this capability is offered in their API. However you can log into their management console and search by the vaultedShopperId there.